# How to merge few rows to one row?

Tags: mysql, database, view

How can I get

```
column1  column2   column3
value1   value2    value3
```

from

```
column1  column2   column3
value1   null      null
null     value2    null
null     null      value3
```

Comment: do the columns belong to one table or different table?

Answer (score 0):

You should use this:

```
SELECT T1.column1, T2.column2, T3.column3 FROM test1 T1
LEFT JOIN test1 T2 ON T2.column2 is not null
LEFT JOIN test1 T3 ON T3.column3 is not null
WHERE T1.column1 is not null
```